# Problem with incorrect display of a field time_waited in view dba_hist_active_sess_history when sessions are blocked

Tags: oracle, blocking

I'm getting this problem

```
SQL> CREATE USER DEMO IDENTIFIED BY DEMO DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS;

User created.

SQL> GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE TO DEMO;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO DEMO;

Grant succeeded.
```

In first session:

```
SQL> CONNECT DEMO/DEMO
Connected.
SQL> CREATE TABLE D_LOCK(DIGIT NUMBER, STRING VARCHAR(10));
Table created.

INSERT INTO D_LOCK VALUES (1, 'ONE');
SQL> 
1 row created.

INSERT INTO D_LOCK VALUES (2, 'TWO');
SQL> 
1 row created.

SQL> COMMIT;
Commit complete.

SQL> UPDATE D_LOCK SET STRING='001' WHERE DIGIT=1;
1 row updated.
```

In second session:

```
SQL> CONNECT DEMO/DEMO
Connected.

SQL> delete from D_LOCK WHERE DIGIT=1;
```

<---the second session hangs while waiting for the first to commit

I make the next request a few seconds later:

```
SELECT
    ash.snap_id,
    ash.sample_time,
    ash.blocking_session as ,
    ash.blocking_session_serial#,
     ' -> '                    as is_blocking,
    ash.session_id as blocked_sid,
    ash.session_serial# as blocked_serial,
    ash.sql_id as blocked_sql_id,
    sql.sql_text as blocked_sql_text,
    ash.sql_opname as blocked_sql_opname,
    ash.event as blocked_event,
    round(ash.time_waited / 1000000) AS blocked_sec
FROM
    dba_hist_active_sess_history   ash,
    v$sql                          sql
WHERE
    blocking_session IS NOT NULL
    AND ash.sql_id = sql.sql_id 
    and BLOCKING_SESSION_STATUS = 'VALID'
    --and time_waited>0 
ORDER BY
    sample_id DESC;
```

But field blocked_sec is 0. Why? There should also be a waiting time (a few seconds).

Answer (score 1):

`dba_hist_active_sess_history` is populated only at ASH snapshot intervals, which defaults to 1 hour apart. It is meant to store older data on disk to be permanently resident and kept for some time (default 8 days). Instead, you should use in-memory data by querying `v$active_session_history` . This view updates every second with each polling blink and stays in memory as long as it can, at least until a snapshot has written it to disk and usually longer (hours typically).

Also, you probably don't want to use `time_waited`. Per the docs:

> Total wait time for the event for which the session last waited if the
> session was on the CPU when sampled; **0 if the session was waiting at
> the time of sampling**

This is not the same as `seconds_in_wait` from `v$session`, as there it is precisely the opposite: it should show 0 if on CPU and non-zero if in wait. There it is the time it has been in the precise wait currently posted (since `session_state` was flipped to `WAITING`). Many back-to-back waits (often sub-second) will constantly reset this to 0 even though cumulative they are adding up clock time. What value ASH or any other polling monitor would show would have to depend on the precise microsecond that it's one-second polling happened to catch the session, making it rarely meaningless. Further, per the docs on ASH and some testing its clear that it's doing something different, even if it uses this value from `v$session` in some way. At any rate, for TX contention like you're testing, it will always show 0.

Therefore, `time_waited` is really not meaningful in the context of ASH data. What you want is to **count the # of rows**. In `v$active_session_history`, one row equals one second of time, so `COUNT(*) secs` (you'll need to `GROUP BY` your other attributes). In `dba_hist_active_sess_history` one row equals (approximates, since it simply retains every tenth record) *ten* seconds of time, so multiply: `COUNT(*)*10 secs`

Comment: I am doing
EXEC DBMS_WORKLOAD_REPOSITORY.create_snapshot; before executing the request

Comment: @Рязанский Крестоносец Did you wait at least 10 seconds? The snapshot that writes to `dba_hist_active_sess_history` only records one out of every 10 rows in `gv$active_session_history`. So you have to have at least 10 seconds of something before you can be sure it'll end up in the history table. Also for this reason, the history table # of rows must e multiplied by 10 to give you total seconds, whereas the `v$` view the # of rows is equal to the # of seconds.

Comment: Yes. I waiting more 20-30 second. Rows appear, but the value in the blocked_sec field is 0

Comment: @Рязанский Крестоносец , I updated my answer about using `time_waited`.